# Apache Camel FTP component from a web application

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I have an apache camel based web application. I have created restful routes using the camel servlet component. I have a requirement where I want to download a file from FTP to the local server when one of the restful URL in my application is invoked. I couldn't find any examples googling for it.

Also is it possible to invoke camel FTP component from a timer or Quartz components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use Quartz in your routePolicy to make the ftp consume for a certain amount of time and then stop:

http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html

If you want to use a Timer, then this will have to in the "From". Then you can use Poll Enrich to consume from FTP:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000")
.pollEnrich("ftp://localhost")
.to("mock:result");
```

Comment: Thanks this is something I was looking for

Comment: Great, I'm glad. Please accept it as the answer so it would help others in the future.